# Python - comparing 2 twodimensional dicts

Tags: python, dictionary

Trying to compare 2 twodimensional dicts in Python

Wrote this code:

```
import collections
import json
import pprint

def dict_compare(d1, d2):
    d1_keys = set(d1.keys())
    d2_keys = set(d2.keys())
    intersect_keys = d1_keys.intersection(d2_keys)
    added = d1_keys - d2_keys
    removed = d2_keys - d1_keys
    modified = {o: (d1[o], d2[o]) for o in intersect_keys if d1[o] != d2[o]}
    same = set(o for o in intersect_keys if d1[o] == d2[o])
    return added, removed, modified, same

checkslist = collections.defaultdict(dict)


checkslist['a'][0]="test1"
checkslist['a'][1]="test2"


with open('checklist.json',"w") as outfile:
    json.dump(checkslist,outfile)


with open('checklist.json',"r") as infile:
    data = json.load(infile)

added, removed, modified, same = dict_compare(data, checkslist)
print(added, removed, modified, same)
```

Unfortunately it does not work well. It detects it as modified.

Output:

```
(set([]), set([]), {'a': ({u'1': u'test2', u'0': u'test1'}, {0: 'test1', 1: 'test2'})}, set([]))
```

3rd set should be empty.

How to correctly compare 2 twodimensional dicts?

Thanks,

**update 1:**

```
checkslistbase = collections.defaultdict(dict)
checkslist = collections.defaultdict(dict)


checkslistbase['a'][0]="test1"
checkslistbase['a'][1]="test2"

checkslist['a'][0]="test1"
checkslist['a'][1]="test3"
```

Want to compare checkslistbase to checklist. In this case it should detect that checkslist['a'][1] was changed (modified). It should also mentioned when stuff was added, removed or what is the same.

Comment: Can you give (small, minimal) examples for `d1` and `d2`?

Comment: @jpp The OP is comparing `checkslist` with a copy of itself that was saved as JSON and reloaded. So it looks like `{'a': {0: 'test1', 1: 'test2'}}`. OTOH, the OP is using Python 2, so there's a plain text to Unicode transformation happening via the JSON stuff. And integer keys get converted to strings, as Jean-François mentions.

Comment: @PM2Ring Tha'ts exactly why jpp is asking for data, so that we can test our solution with dummy data.

Comment: @BramVanroy I totally agree that a MCVE should supply test data. But in this case, the test data is embedded in the code itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison function is okay.

The problem is that the serialization of the dictionary converts the integer keys as strings.

```
checkslist['a'][0]="test1"
checkslist['a'][1]="test2"
```

when you dump that you get:

```
{"a": {"0": "test1", "1": "test2"}}
```

use `checkslist.copy()` to compare with `data` or use string keys and it'll work with `json`:

```
checkslist['a']["0"]="test1"
checkslist['a']["1"]="test2"
```

(yet another alternative would be compare the keys with a `str` conversion but that forces to change a lot of stuff in your code and forces to recreate almost every input)

If you need some alternate python-only serialization use `str(dict(checkslist))` to write the dict (you need to convert it to a standard dict to be able to parse it back) and `ast.literal_eval` to parse it back, so the distinction between integer & strings in dictionary keys are preserved.

```
with open('checklist.json',"w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(dict(checkslist)))

with open('checklist.json',"r") as infile:
    data = ast.literal_eval(infile.read())
```

with those changes your code prints (as expected):

```
set() set() {} {'a'}
```

Answer (score 0):

The third set is

```
{'a': ({u'1': u'test2', u'0': u'test1'}, {0: 'test1', 1: 'test2'})}
```

The values for `a` key are:

```
V1 = {u'1': u'test2', u'0': u'test1'}

V2 = {0: 'test1', 1: 'test2'}
```

Problem: `V1` is different from `V2` because `V1` uses string as keys while `V2` uses integer as keys.